# Java logic error - If statements

Tags: java, date

I need to test whether a String input date of (mm/dd/yyyy) is valid. The criteria is that of a normal calendar, specifically with my problem the month needs to be between 1 and 12. For whatever reason if I enter what should be a valid month, and the input itself should be true based on my if statement, my program is reading it as false.

For instance if I input 01/01/2000, the int month will = 1. Therefore the month is greater than 0 and less than 13. But instead the program reads it as false and I can't figure out why. Thanks

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C3PP4_Benjamin_Crosta_CTIM15701 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputDate, monthString, dayString, yearString;
        boolean validMonth, leapYear;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );

        //user input
        System.out.println("Please enter date. (mm/dd/yyyy)");
        inputDate = keyboard.nextLine();

        //PROCESSING
        monthString = inputDate.substring(0, 2);
        dayString = inputDate.substring(3, 5);
        yearString = inputDate.substring(6, 10);

        //String to int conversion
        int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dayString);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);

        //months 
        if ((month > 0 && month < 13)) validMonth = true;
        else validMonth = false;
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the month you entered does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (month > 0 && month < 13){
validMonth = true;
} else {
validMonth = false;
System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the month you entered does not exist.");
}
```

If you do not use curly brackets it will only execute one line below, also use single brackets for this if statement

You can also use split by ('/'):

```
String date = "01/01/1970";
String[] split = date.split("/");
int day = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
```

Comment: OHHHH ok, I thought brackets were only needed for nested if-else statements. It works now thank you